# how to set Multi Role based auth guard (firebase) for user in angular 13?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire, angular13

I have successfully authorized logged in user to view some of my pages. Now I want to show few pages to only admin role user. i.e `isAdmin = true` but unable to achieve this target below is my code.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

 @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class AdminAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  isAdmin: boolean;

 constructor(
   public db: AngularFirestore,
   private userService: UserService,
   public auth: AuthService,
   private router: Router
  ) {
  }
  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  get isAuthenticated(): boolean {
       return this.auth.isAdmin;
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Could you show or explain, how the `isAdmin` field in the `AuthService` is filled?

Comment: Would for example be interesting to know, if your role is stored in the Firestore database or in the auth token.